# ELMAH regex REMOTE_ADDR filter not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

ELMAH generates an exception like below when a known process visits a non-existing URL on our website:

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/manager/' was not
>   found or does not implement IController.

Whereas going to that non-existent URL from a browser generates a typical IIS 404.

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /manager

I know the process accessing these addresses is harmless, and want to stop receiving these specific emails being generated from a range of IP addresses. This is what I have in web.config but ELMAH email still comes through.

The URL filter seems to be working fine.

```
      <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
        <errorMail from="elmah@mydomain.com" to="elmahlog@mydomain.com" async="true" smtpServer="mail.mydomain.com" smtpPort="25" useSsl="false" />
        <errorFilter>
          <test>
            <and>
              <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="500" type="Int32" />
              <or>
                <!--TrustWave scans our website with intentional bad addresses-->
                <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['REMOTE_ADDR']" pattern="64.37.231.\d{1,3}" type="String" />

                <!--Google looking for Digital Asset Links - well known statements the website wants to make-->
              <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" pattern="/.well-known/assetlinks.json" type="String" />

                <!--Apple devices searching for universal links - app-site association. we dont have an app.-->
                <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" pattern="/.well-known/apple-app-site-association" type="String" />            
              </or>
            </and>
          </test>
        </errorFilter>
      </elmah>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though ELMAH email message looks like a 500 error occurred, the web.config really needed a 404 error code for the filter to work.

`<equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />`

instead of

`<equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="500" type="Int32" />`